# to input data to a function

Tags: c

her i am inputting the data through printf

```
printf("enter the src ipaddress \n");
scanf("%s",buff);
inet_aton(buff, &(delete_node.ip.ip_src));

printf("enter the dst ip address\n");
scanf("%s",buff);
inet_aton(buff, &(delete_node.ip.ip_dst));

printf("enter the source port\n");
scanf("%d",port);
delete_node.protocol.proto.uh_sport = ntohs(port);

printf("enter the destination port\n");
scanf("%d",port);
delete_node.protocol.proto.uh_dport = ntohs(port);
```

i want to write a function which inputs the above parameter how to write it ? here i am inputting it the data to place i want to store it. like delete_node.ip.ip_src and so on, where delete_node is a structure. how to write a function which performs the same task that of the above printf statements

Answer (score 1):

Have the function receive a pointer to the struct and use it inside:

```
int fx(struct WHATEVER *node) {
    printf("...");
    scanf("%s", buff); /* validate! */
    inet_aton(buff, &(node->ip.ip_src));
    /* ... */
    return 0; /* all ok */
}
```